# Raiserror SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an insert statement :

```
Insert into foo (id, value) 
Values (1, 5)
```

Is there any way to raise an error when value is for example -1

```
Insert into foo (Id, value)
Values (1, case when -1=-1 then raiserror() else 5 end)
```

Comment: Difficult to tell what you're actually looking for here. Do you maybe want a `check constraint` on the table?

Comment: I just want to know is there any way to this or not? And don't want to use constraint

Comment: Can you write the *literal* code included in your question and it execute? No. But you could discover that yourself. So you need to add more *context* to your question. What are you actually trying to achieve? My (and Tim's, apparently) suspicion is that you want to prevent a particular value from being inserted into the table (no matter how the attempt is made).

Comment: @AliTheOne You ask if there is a way. Yes there is. Can you do it within a single tsql insert statement? No. With questions like this, there is a reason others question the premise - because you are likely trying to do something that is inconsistent with the design/architecture of the platform you are using.

Comment: @SMor thank you for your time I just check that in my program

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a check constraint, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
    id int primary key,
    value int NOT NULL CHECK (value >= 0)
)
```

If the table `foo` already exists, then you can use `ALTER TABLE` to add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD CONSTRAINT ck_value CHECK (value >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Raiseerror()` method is supported in stored procedure.

Better to write insert query into stored procedure and apply validation like below:

```
IF (@value < 0) 
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Invalid parameter: @value cannot be less than zero', 18, 0)
    RETURN
END
```